# PowerShell Export-CSV format

Tags: csv, powershell

I may be asking for too much. I've been tasked with writing a PowerShell script that will extract file share info. Here's an example scenario:

Start with a list of three servers.
Each server has five fixed disks.
Each fixed disk has ten shares.
Each share ACL lists fifteen groups with various read/write permissions.

Doing the math, that's 2,250 discrete pieces of information.

My script is finished, but all it does is spit out the information into a text file, which is cumbersome to work with. Management much prefers spreadsheets that they can sort-n-filter.

But I can't figure out how to take that river of info and format it into one csv file. What should the column headers be? Each cell would be something like: "Server 1, Disk C, Share ABC, Group Marketing, Permission Read", "Server 2, Disk D, Share XYZ, Group Finance, Permission Full Control", and so on.

Comment: This question will result in an opinion based answer.  How does your management want to see the information?

Answer (score 0):

How to output this depends on what objects you're script are creating and due to the lack of a sample there's not much we can help you with other than saying that this is possible to do.

The only question I see here is

> What should the column headers be?

Here's my suggestion:

```
Server,Disk,Share,Identity,Permission
```